# Setting ID Fields for Updates

Tags: api-27

"Setting ID Fields for Updates" is the new feature in Spring13 release. But I am not understanding it very much. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some further release notes here - [Spring '13 Force.com Platform Release 
Setting ID Fields for Updates](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Spring13/Setting+ID++Fields+for+Updates)

Basically, you can create an sObject in Apex and specify the Id value via the property. You can then pass this sObject to a DML update without having to first query that same record with SOQL.

E.g. Using API v27.0 (or later)

```
Account a = new Account();
a.Phone = '123456789';
// Set the Id that you found through some means
a.Id = '001800000000001';
update a;
```

Prior to this you would have needed to specify the Id in the sObject constructor.

Comment: But that we can also do like Account a = new Account(Id=someid); update a; So what is the difference?

Comment: @doga, only that you can do it later via the property rather than in the constructor. Could be useful if another class is calling the constructor for you. You could use it to query one Account, change the Id to a second Accounts, and then update the second account with the firsts details.

Comment: I think Id fields used to be not writeable (but I've tried now even with API v20 and it works, weird?). For me it doesn't matter how I use the feature (set id in constructor or later as a property) - I know I can now make "homemade" rollup summaries in trigger with COUNT()/SUM() in query and then I don't need to query for the object to rollup to, I can simply specify Id (which I know is OK because I grouped by it) and new value ;) So a bit less code and a bit less query rows wasted ;)

Comment: @eyescream  Could you please tell some scenarios where it could be usefull.

Comment: @DanielBallinger  Could you please tell some scenarios where it could be usefull.

Comment: @doga, I think we've covered it. If you know the sObject Id, you don't need to pull the record out with SOQL first. You can just set the Id property and call update. Eyescream gave the aggregate-group by example. I gave the Account field copy example. There will be lots of other possible uses. It's just another option for when you need it.